# How do i start to implement docopt to my python class

Tags: python, command-line-interface, docopt

I have the following python class working and i want to create a command line interface for the user to use. I came across docopt and thought it was a good idea to use. I haven't come across a tutorial or documentation showing how to integrate docopt to your python classes all i get is just small functions . Is it possible? A link with helpful infromation would help me out or just a small snippet to help me work out my way would be very helpful.

```
class Bootcamp(object):
    tasks = {1: "TDD", 2: "OOP", 3: "Programming Logic", 4:
         "Version Control", 5: "Agile Methodology",
         6: "Growth Mindset", 7: "Asking Questions", 8:
         "Motivation and Commitment", 9: "Speaking"}

    def __init__(self, name, tasks=tasks):
        self.name = name
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.completed = []
        self.incompleted = tasks.values()

    def add_completed_items(self, i):
        if i in self.tasks.keys():
            self.completed.append(self.tasks[i])
            self.incompleted.remove(self.tasks[i])
            return "tasks added to complete"
        else:
            return "not in the tasks"

    def check_progress(self):
        self.progress = float(len(self.completed)) / \
             float(len(self.tasks)) * 100
        return int(self.progress)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate docopt to your python classes" ? Maybe you are looking for docstrings?

Comment: I want to create a cli interface for my class using docopt

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to interact with your class via the cli?

Comment: Its a class that was designed for a user to check tasks he or she has to do. The user can add the tasks that have been done and even check the progress in percentage using the check_progress method. Maybe the user could give his name, then check on the tasks and can later check the tasks that he has completed. He can view the remaining tasks.

Comment: `nick = Bootcamp("nick")`
`print nick.tasks`
`print nick.add_completed_items(1)`
`print nick.add_completed_items(2)`
`print nick.add_completed_items(3)`
`print nick.incompleted`
`print nick.completed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docopt` [GitHub page](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) has a description.

---

For instance:

```
"""Naval Fate.

Usage:
  naval_fate.py ship new <name>...
  naval_fate.py ship <name> move <x> <y> [--speed=<kn>]
  naval_fate.py ship shoot <x> <y>
  naval_fate.py mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored | --drifting]
  naval_fate.py (-h | --help)
  naval_fate.py --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  --speed=<kn>  Speed in knots [default: 10].
  --moored      Moored (anchored) mine.
  --drifting    Drifting mine.

"""
from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='Naval Fate 2.0')
    print(arguments)
```

I'm not certain that `docopt` is designed for what you hope to do, though. It's designed for handling command-line parameters when a script is called, not an entire command-line interface.

Comment: That's what i was asking whether it can make a CLI for an app. I guess i will just use it as a user guide to help in running my class

Comment: You might get better use from [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/prompts/).